# Regex: A pattern that searches for a string except when it is the content between a set of characters

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that indicates all occurrences of a specific sub-strings (alphanumerical: spaces, numbers, symbols, letters) within a string except when it is between two sets of characters.

For example:

```
This is a string that contains multiple <span class="string">occurrences</span> of the word string.
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the first and the last occurances of the word string, but not the second since it is between span & span.

Comment: have you tried some regex patterns so far ?

Comment: Checkout regex "lookarounds":

[Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  

What you need is to check if "string" is perceeded and followed by a span element.  
Lookahead/lookbehind should do the job.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I am looking for the first and third occurrence.

Comment: What about `<span></span> string <span></span>`? It's between two sets of characters as well.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: I think he's looking for words not inside the tags themself (like an attribute for example). so the set of characters is probably `<` and `>`. Or not <°)))))))))))>

Comment: That's not what the question states, nor what the accepted answer does.

Comment: Curious to know why my question was down voted...

Comment: Searching for an attribute or part of it atleast. Wanted to exclude a specific word because I had already enclosed it with an span element during a loop. Problem is that the span element contains long custom attributes that might contain words that are found during future loops and enclosed again.

Comment: @BarryBrian: using DOMDocument to edit your content will solve many of your problems since with this tool you can target tags or text nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$string = 'This is a "string" that contains multiple <span class="string">occurrences</span> of the word string.';
$target = 'string';
preg_match_all('~<.+?>.*?</.+?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(' . preg_quote($target) . ')~', $string, $matches);
echo 'Found:' . count($matches[1]) . ' occurances of ' . $target . '.';
```

Output:

> Found:2 occurances of string.

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html

Demo (with explanation):
https://regex101.com/r/yG2dS3/1

I also changed your provided string a bit (`"string"` instead of `string` to start) because my first regexs were working but shouldn't have so I quoted the string outside the element as well.

I'm not sure why the first `?` and the text after it are black instead of red but this example is/was working for me. It can be seen working here, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c97f4c257bc8cb09f4da14db34727d27bde0181 as well.

Comment: Very neat, much appreciated.

Comment: Just for the record, this won't match `a <b>formatted string</b>`, though it's impossible to tell from the question whether it should or not.

Comment: The question states it shouldn't be able to. Feel free to edit the qeustion if is not specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this regex :

`(<string(\s|\S)*?<\/string>)|(<\/?(\s|\S)*?>)` it works fine for detecting the word "string" in a HTML element. Try using http://regexr.com/ to see how it works exactly.

**EDIT :**

If you want to do this for every HTML elements (like `<script>`, `<div id="hello">` and so on, you can use this one :

```
<(\/*?)(?!(em|p|br\s*\/|strong))\w+?.+?>
```